# convert factor and character to numeric in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a dataframe that I am trying to filter.  Here is the structure:

```
'dataframe': 45 obs. of 1450 variables:
$ X01493112  :Factor w/ 47 levels "01493112", "0145769",...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr "510130020" "510360002"
```

I have a feeling I can't filter it because I have factors and characters but I cannot convert it to numeric. I have tried:

```
as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}
df2 <- as.numeric.factor(df1)
```

and numerous other conversions but I can't figure out why it won't work, when I call the new df I get

```
>numeric(0)
```

Comment: Are you using an arithmetic condition for the filter? It would help to add more about the filtering beforehand.

Comment: That doesn't look like the standard `str()` of a data frame (`'dataframe'` should be `'data.frame'`).  What is `class(df1)`?

Comment: if possible, just use `read.whatever(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to have some example data to work with, but try:

```
df$your_factor_variable_now_numeric <- 
                as.numeric(as.character(df$your_old_factor_variable))
```

And use it only to convert a factor variable, not the complete dataframe. You can also have a look at `type.convert`. If you want to convert all factors in the dataframe, you can use something along the lines

```
 df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Note that this converts all factors and might not be what you want if you have factors that do not represent numeric values. If unnecessary conversion is a problem, or if there are non-numeric factors or characters in the data, the following would be appropriate:

```
 numerify <- function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x
 df[] <- lapply(df, numerify)
```

On a more general point though, the type of your variables should not prevent you from filtering, if, with filtering, you mean subsetting the dataframe. However, the type conversion should be solved with the above code.

Comment: The `lapply` will not only convert all factor columns but all columns in the data set

Comment: Just use an index, for example `idx <- sapply(df, is.factor); df[idx] <- lapply(df[idx], ...)`

Comment: I agree. However, in this case we are talking about 45 observations with 1450 columns. This inefficiency is unlikely to be noticeable.

Comment: That's still bad practice.. Also, you are ignoring quite an important problem. Look what happens to character vectors (columns): `as.numeric(as.character(letters))`

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my solution to reflect your very good points. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun1 <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))
fun2 <- function(x) as.numeric(x)

fac_to_num <- function(y) modifyList(y,lapply(y[sapply(y,is.factor)],fun1))

char_to_num <- function(y) modifyList(y,lapply(y[sapply(y,is.factor)],fun2))
```

Apply `fac_to_num` to the columns in your data for factor -> numeric conversion, `char_to_num` for character to numeric conversion.